# jQuery input converter?

Tags: jquery, html, converters

Simple PPC ROI Calculator. I need to input 4 variables and have them convert on the front end. I'm new to Javascript and could use some help with this one.

I need to figure out how to make the input boxes auto-update in the `span` areas in my html. I know I need functions around each `getElementByID` script but I have no clue where to begin, or how. I can't find anything else online.

The math should be correct, but having it update below after you input the 4 boxes is tricky. Can anyone provide assistance to a learner? I was able to create all of this from scratch as is, so at least I'm not a complete noob, right? ... right?

```
<script>

    var // variables
        clicks_purchased = $('#clicks_purchased').val(),
        cost_per_click = $('#cost_per_click').val(),
        rate = $('#rate').val(),
        conversion = clicks_purchased * rate,
        avg_purchase = $('#avg_purchase').val(),
        // calculations
        total = clicks_purchased * cost_per_click,
        responders = clicks_purchased,
        buyers = conversion * clicks_purchased,
        revenue = buyers * avg_purchase,
        profit = revenue - total,
        cost_per_responder = cost_per_click,
        cost_per_buyer = cost_per_click / conversion;

    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
    document.getElementById("responders").innerHTML = responders;
    document.getElementById("buyers").innerHTML = buyers;
    document.getElementById("revenue").innerHTML = revenue;
    document.getElementById("profit").innerHTML = profit;
    document.getElementById("cost_per_responder").innerHTML = cost_per_responder;
    document.getElementById("cost_per_buyer").innerHTML = cost_per_buyer;

</script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
        <div class="calculator">
            <input id="clicks_purchased" type="text" placeholder="Number">
            <input id="cost_per_click" type="text" placeholder="Dollar">
            <input id="rate" type="text" placeholder="Percentage">
            <input id="avg_purchase" type="text" placeholder="Dollar">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 columns">
        <div class="results">
            <h1>Expected Results:</h1>
            <div>
                Total: <span id="total"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                Responders: <span id="responders"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                Buyers: <span id="buyers"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                Revenue: <span id="revenue"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                Profit: <span id="profit"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                Cost per Responder: <span id="cost_per_responder"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                Cost per Buyer: <span id="cost_per_buyer"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: fyi: if you are in fact using jquery you can replace `document.getElementById("total").innerHTML` with `$(#total).html()`

Comment: Excellent. Should parsing a variable through this operator look like this? `$(#total).html(total);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a function, and call that function when the user leaves a textbox (on blur)

```
function computeROI(){
    var clicks_purchased = $('#clicks_purchased').val(),
        cost_per_click = $('#cost_per_click').val(),
        rate = $('#rate').val(),
        conversion = clicks_purchased * rate,
        avg_purchase = $('#avg_purchase').val(),
        // calculations
        total = clicks_purchased * cost_per_click,
        responders = clicks_purchased,
        buyers = conversion * clicks_purchased,
        revenue = buyers * avg_purchase,
        profit = revenue - total,
        cost_per_responder = cost_per_click,
        cost_per_buyer = cost_per_click / conversion;

    $("#total").html(total);
    $("#responders").html(responders);
    $("#buyers").html(buyers);
    $("#revenue").html(revenue);
    $("#profit").html(profit);
    $("#cost_per_responder").html(cost_per_responder);
    $("#cost_per_buyer").html(cost_per_buyer);
};

$('input').on('blur', computeROI);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7daffjh8/15/

Comment: This did the trick! Learned a lot from this post. Thank you for your corrections, effort, and time. Added the `.noConflict()` wrapper in WordPress, parsed and minified JS through Gulp, and we're smooth sailing from here on out. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have your Javascript execute once an input is changed. To do this with jQuery, you will need to bind each input element to a `change` event. You'll also want to wrap the JS code you posted in a function, as below:

```
function calculate() {
    var // variables
        clicks_purchased = $('#clicks_purchased').val(),
    //...etc
}
// On DOM ready
$(function() {
    $('input').on('change', function() {
        // Do this for each element
        calculate();
    });
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/bcfL25o3/.

Comment: Confirmed that this also works. Thank you for your time! It's nice seeing a pure javascript solution to this as well.